# Xamarin android emulator causes windows 10 blue screen ( clock watchdog timeout error )

Tags: android

First of all ı am new on xamarin visual studio 2019 .So ı set up xamarin and whenever ı run Android emulator , emulator work but after few seconds windows 10 has crashed and it restart itself. Also I opened hyper v features but still doesn't work

Can you help my problem ?

Comment: Do you have more logs to share ? It's a bit light to help you :/

Comment: My pc features are : i7 -6700hQ 16gb ram and firstly I prefer xamarin adnroid emulatör 8.1 oreo , android SDK platform 17 . When ı run blank project xamarin android emulator , that is run and open 2-3 seconds after causes windows restart

Answer (score 0):

ı did a lot of search for my this problem and I had a find soultion something. That is a windows update error. When my windows features series 1809 , ı had take this error. But when ı update to windows series 2004 I didn't take blue screen error. So maybe İf you are getting this error , can try update your system